# ipad 2 back up has become corrupt

Tags: ipad

Since I updated my iPad 2 to 7.1.1, whenever I try to connect to iTunes the message come up saying the back up [image]

Any help how to overcome this problem. Thanks

Comment: backups are located at ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/

Comment: Thanks however how to overcome this corruption problem?

Comment: delete or zip the existing backups, try again.